# Is there any option for using Codeigniter, Doctrine and PostgreSQL together?

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, doctrine

When i make a change in settings of CI about database for postgre i take a exception about Doctrine cant sense dbdriver. What can i do for this? I'm trying to change my DB server from MYSQL to POSTGRESQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ForumAnswer](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/131807/#925186) on CI site. In CI config:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "postgre";
```

Doctrine 1.2, supported [DB drivers](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction-to-connections/en#introduction-to-connections)

Doctrine 2.0, supported [DB drivers](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html)

Note that you have to change protocol part of `DSN` to something like `pgsql` for Doctrine 1.2 or database option `'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql'` for Doctrine2